# call deleteRowsAtIndexPaths multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

There are several questions about this problem. I have tried all of the suggested answers but nothing has worked yet. 
So I have this `func` which decline offers that a user receives. I can decline the offers and delete the cell rows but when there is only one cell left I get `fatal error: Index out of range`

```
func declineButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
    let buttonRow = sender.tag  // this is the tag from my custom cell button
    let offer = offers[buttonRow]  // I get the error here 
    let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    loadingNotification.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.Indeterminate
    loadingNotification.labelText = "declining offer...."
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "\(ipAddress)/api/v1.0/offers.php")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "id=\(offer.id!)&action=decline&offer_id=\(offer.offer_id!)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true) 
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
        { data, response, error in

            if error != nil {

                let messageToDisplay = error                    
                self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true

                return

            }


            do{
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON = json{

                    let resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String

                       if resultValue == "Success"{


                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                            print("before count is \(self.offers.count)") // before the error the count is 2 here
                            self.offers.removeAtIndex(buttonRow) //update my model
                            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: buttonRow, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
                            print("after count is \(self.offers.count)") //then the count is 1 here      
                            MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)

                            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true

                        }


                     }else{

                        //no success    
                }
             }


         } catch{

      }

  }

    task.resume()

}
```

inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I assign the tag value of the button

```
offerCell.declineButton.tag = indexPath.row
offerCell.declineButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(OpenDealsDetailsViewController.declineButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

******UPDATE*****

I think I found the error. When I print 
`print("button row is\(buttonRow)")` the number don't get updated. So the first time it calls the correct row but the second times it keep the indexPath.row it had when `declineButtonTapped` was called the first time

`button row is0
before count is 2
after count is 1
button row is1 // this of course should be 0 as there is only one cell left
fatal error: Index out of range`

if I try to do

```
self.offers.removeAtIndex(buttonRow)                                
self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: buttonRow, inSection:   0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

I get the following error:

`Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).`

Comment: what's the value for tag which is assigned to your custom cell?

Answer (score 1):

You either shouldn't use tags or you should reload the table view fully after each change. Alternately you could iterate the visible cells and update their tag values.

If you were to always and only delete the last row from the table it'd be fine. As soon as you delete an earlier row all the rows after that now have an incorrect tag value. So, when you go to the last row it doesn't actually exist at that tag, and any other invalid rows will result in you deleting the wrong item from the server.

A better approach is to pass the cell an instance of a class which can action the deletion and call back to the view controller with details of the update made. The view controller can then update its data source and the table view. In this way you separate the table index path from the action you're going to take on the data.

Comment: of course if I change `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` with `reloadData` I don't get the above error but I prefer the first. Can you explain the last option you suggested? can you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: the reason you're using the tag is that it looks simple, the other solution i propose is more complex and harder to explain. As a first run you could pass the data object to the cell and setup a delegate from the cell back to the controller which passes the data object when the button is tapped. Then the VC can find the correct current index path for that data item. My main proposition is similar to that but uses another class to separate the code better.

Comment: Thanks for that. So basically, either I use reloadData() so the table get reloaded every time I delete one cell or I have to use a more complex approach. Being this a MVP I think I will go for the easier solution. ;)